# AWS SDK PHP (2) cURL Timeout Security Check

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, timeout

Having some trouble with this code:

```
$ec2 = Ec2Client::factory(array(
        'AWS_KEY' => AWS_KEY,
        'AWS_SECRET_KEY' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    )); 

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($ec2->describeInstances());
```

I'm constantly receiving this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 28: Connection time-out [url] http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/' in /**/**/**/htdocs/**/vendor/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php:578
```

I also receive this if I use `$aws = AWS::factory()` followed by `$ec2 = $aws->get('ec2')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is because you haven't specified the key and secret key properly so the code is (automatically) trying to get the IAM credentials from that URL.

You should use 'key' and 'secret' in your array.

```
$ec2 = Ec2Client::factory(array(
        'key' => AWS_KEY,
        'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ));
```

Comment: Bah, such a simple thing. Thanks.